# Docker cURL one container from another

Tags: docker

Theres a good chance I'm being dumb here, but I have the following endpoint which works in the browser and returns a result:

http://localhost:8000/api/ebay/getSellers

This is on my `app` Docker container, and I want to use cURL on my `api` container to retrieve the result.

My dockerfile looks like so:

```
services:
    server:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/prod/nginx.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/prod/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        container_name: toolkit-server
        image: my/toolkit-server:latest
        depends_on:
            - app
            - api
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/prod/php.dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
        container_name: toolkit-app
        image: my/toolkit-app:latest
    api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/prod/api.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8100:80"
        volumes:
            - ./api:/var/www/html/
        container_name: toolkit-api
        image: my/toolkit-api:latest
```

I've tried using cURL like so:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/ebay/getSellers
http://app:8000/api/ebay/getSellers
http://toolkit-app:8000/api/ebay/getSellers
```

But the respose I get is always:

```
Failed to connect to toolkit-app port 8000: Connection refused
```

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

Sorry to clarify, my curl is within the `api` container and I want to query the `app` container

Comment: How about `http://toolkit-app/api/ebay/getSellers`?

Comment: Your title says ´curl from one container to another', but your text sounds like you want to curl from the host to the api container. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah sorry my curl is within the api container and I want to query the app container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're querying the wrong port.

In your compose file, you have this configuration for your `app` container :

```
ports:
  - "8000:80"
```

This block means that you're mapping the port 80 **from the container** to the port 8000 **on your host**. It is always `port_on_host:port_on_container`

So if you want to access the `app` container from the `api` container, you need to curl with this url :

`curl http://app:80/api/ebay/getSellers`

Answer (score 1):

The api container is mapping the services port 80 to the external port 8100.

Try to request http://localhost:8100/